# Laravel: Fetching records from matching array data

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having trouble fetching records from a table that matches the data below:

**$request->cardColor** contains:

```
    0 => "White"
    1 => "Green"
```

I'd like to to fetch records from my `cards` table that *exactly* matches the data above to its `colors` column. A sample (array) entry in this column would be `["White","Green","Red","Blue"]`

With this, I would like to be able to fetch entries with strictly White *and* Green values only. Hoping to be able to build a proper query for this.

Please feel free to ask clarification questions, and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the usage of `whereJsonContains()` and `whereJsonLength()` to achieve the desire result, for example:

```
$colors = $request->cardColor;
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('cards')
    ->whereJsonContains('colors', $colors)
    ->whereJsonLength('colors', count($colors))
    ->get();
```

The call to `whereJsonContains()` allows you to check whether the values inside the column exists or not, and the call to `whereJsonLength()` is necessary since you want the `colors` column to contain the exact same amount of elements as in `$request->cardColors`.

Comment: Thanks Eyad. Unfortunately I'm getting this error "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION my_database.json_contains does not exist (SQL: select * from `cards` where json_contains(`colors`, ["White","Green"]) and json_length(`colors`) = 2)". Could it be because my column type is TEXT instead of JSON?

Comment: @fufubrocat This code should work even if your column type is `TEXT` as long as it contains a valid JSON string. The error message says that the `JSON_CONTAINS()` function doesn't exist, so I suspect that you may have a MySQL version older than 5.7.8.

Comment: Eyad you're correct. Just had to update MariaDB to >= 10.2. Thank you so much for your feedback!

Comment: @fufubrocat You're more than welcome my friend! I wish you success in your career!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all records that have value of column `colors` contained in your entry array:
`DB::table('your_table')->whereIn('column_name', your_array)->get();`

Comment: I think he's storing JSON, and he meant to select all rows where the `colors` column contains only a specific array of values.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood his question @@